# Overwrite MVC validationsummary with generic message

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

Is there a way to display a generic "please correct fields" message in my `Html.ValidationSummary()` instead of the list of individual errors? The spec I am working with only required a generic message as each field has inline hover messages with the error information.

Many thanks

Comment: What has been tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first parameter is true because we want the summary displays model-level errors only and the second parameter is the message

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "please correct field")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you pass `true` to `Html.ValidationSummary` it will only display model-level errors there (errors not directly tied to any one field):

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
```